# UnboundLocalError: local variable 'x' referenced before assignment

Tags: python, python-3.x, variable

При нажатии на кнопку печатается ошибка. (python3)

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'uni' referenced before assignment
```

Помогите. Вот мой код:

```
from tkinter import *
from os import *
root = Tk()
root.title("changer")
root.geometry("800x450")
unim = "changes"
global uni
uni = 1

def click1():
    if uni == 1:
        unim = "unit not ok"
        uni = 2
    elif uni == 2:
        unim = "unit ok"
        uni = 1
    else:
        uni = 1

app = Frame(root)
app.grid()
btn = Button(text="Change message", command=click1)
btn.grid()
lbl = Label(app, text = unim)
lbl.grid()

root.mainloop()
quit()
```

Answer (score 1):

В тексте ошибки, сказано, что вы пытаетесь работать с переменной, до того, как объявили ее. Это потому что функция пытается работать с локальной переменной `uni`, которой по сути внутри функции не существует.

Это тоже самое, что написать такой код:

```py
a = a + 10
print(a)
```

Интерпретатор не знает переменной `a`, к которой вы пытаетесь прибавить `10`, да еще и вывести на экран, поэтому выдаст ту же самую ошибку.

---

Чтобы избавиться от проблемы, нужно указать функции на то, что с переменной `uni` нужно работать как с глобальной переменной, которая будет меняться за пределами функции во всем коде.

Именно поэтому непонятно для чего вы написали `global uni` за переделами функции, в то время, как **указатель на глобальную переменную нужно размещать в теле функции**

Если хочется узнать что-то еще, подробнее можно почитать [**здесь**](https://python-scripts.com/scope).